# How to update numbers of an existing text file?

Tags: java

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/1Cmg5Rt8

The program asks the user for their name.

It then generates random math problems, and counts correct answers and incorrect answers.

The user is rewarded $0.05 for correct answers and penalized $0.03 for incorrect answers.

All of the above has been done.

I am stuck starting from here:

A file is created using their name.

The amount of answers they got correct/incorrect are recorded to a text file.

If a file under their name already exists, I must combine their results with the results of the ones on the file.

Example of existing text file:

```
Correct answers: 1 

Incorrect answers: 0

Earnings: $0.05
```

If the user runs the program again and gets 1 correct answer, it must be updated like this:

```
Correct answers: 2 

Incorrect answers: 0

Earnings: $0.10
```

Currently, instead of updating, it is being overwritten.
If I choose show stats at the beginning, this is the result (it uses the initialized values):

```
Correct answers:0 

Incorrect answers: 0

Earnings: $0.00
```

I have spent hours trying to figure this out. I refuse to sleep until I solve this. Someone please help me. I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: So first read the existing file, update the stats in memory, then write out the new file.

Comment: @JonSkeet Unfortunately, I have no idea how to write it. I've attempted it earlier. Didn't go so well...

Comment: Hint: search `java write text file` in your favorite search engine.

Comment: From the question, it sounds like you already know how to *write* the file. So you need to concentrate on *reading* the file. Unfortunately, saying "didn't go so well" doesn't tell us anything about what you tried or what happened. Please provide a [mcve] with the code *in the question* (not off on another site, and not hundreds of lines of code - just a minimal example of the problem).

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the name in /before/ you retrieve the stats, i.e. your main method should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    validateCreditsResponse();
    name();
    retrieveStats();
    menu();
    saveStats();
}
```

Also, in this method, you need to also output a println like you do in the 'else' branch:

```
    if (money > 0) {
        outputfile.printf("Earnings: $%.2f", money);
        // Add outputfile.println();
    }
```

Finally, in this method you need to *read* in the data:

```
//Creates new text file for the user unless one already exists.
public static void retrieveStats() {


    try {

        writer = new FileWriter(userName + "Stats.txt", true);
        outputfile = new PrintWriter (writer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

You would start doing this with a FileReader, rather than a FileWriter.

For example in Java 8, like this:

```
//Reads existing text file for the user.
public static void retrieveStats() {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(userName + "Stats.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            Matcher correctMatcher = Pattern.compile("Correct Answers:(.*)").matcher(line);
            if (correctMatcher.matches()) {
                correct = Integer.valueOf(correctMatcher.group(1));
            }

            // TODO complete other matchers

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: So should I be extracting the integers from text file in the while loop and adding them to my new results? If so, how would I extract the integers from the text file?

Comment: Yes. Consider using a regular expression.

Comment: I put ' correct = Integer.parseInt(line); ' in the while loop. Doesn't seem to be working. Am I on the right track?

Comment: That won't work because the rest of the text is also in the line.  I've updated my answer for you.